# Cypress cy.visit() is not redirecting to correct URL

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to bypass the UI login by using cy.request() to log a user in and cy.visit() to go to the restricted route. I have followed this doc: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/testing-your-app#Bypassing-your-UI

However, the test fails because the visit URL ('http://localhost:3000/join-or-create') is not loaded and instead the home page URL is loaded (http://localhost:3000/).

This is my test code:

```
describe('when user is signed in but has not joined a group', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.request('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/api/testing/reset');
    const user = {
      name: 'Joe Bloggs',
      email: 'Joe@Bloggs.com',
      password: 'Password',
    };
    cy.request('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/register', user);
    cy.request('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/sign-in', user);
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/join-or-create');
  });

  it.only('should allow a logged in user to join or create a group', () => {
    cy.contains('Join a group');
    cy.contains('Create a group');
  });
});
```

If I change cy.contains('Join a group'); to cy.contains('Welcome'); (which is content on the URL 'http://localhost:3000/') then the test passes.

If I use:

```
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000');
cy.get('[data-testid="email"]').type('Joe@Bloggs.com');
cy.get('[data-testid="password"]').type('Password');
cy.contains('sign in').click();
```

instead of cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/join-or-create'); the test passes.

The output of the test body shows that is redirecting to a new URL 'http://localhost:3000/' (as shown in the screenshot below) but I can't figure out why.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

In the bypass code, check the response from the POST request

```js
cy.request('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/sign-in', user)
  .then(response => console.log(response))
```

to see what tokens are returned.

Then in the form-login code, look at what happens to the same token after `cy.contains('sign in').click()` and see where the browser stores same token.

That's ***probably*** the step missing in the bypass code. You'll need to add something to do the same, e.g

```js
cy.request('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/sign-in', user)
  .then(response => {
    const token = response.body.token;  // figure out where the token is in response
    cy.setCookie(token);                // figure out where the app want's the token
  })
```

It's also difficult to tell from the question what URL you need to `cy.visit()` in the bypass code, but there's only a couple of them so try both permutations.

Comment: I'm using http-only cookies so I can't access the cookie from the header unfortunately. But logging the response to the sign-in request does show that the cookie is set.